# Mi página web no me carga Jquery, pero a otras personas si

Tags: jquery

lo que me sucede es lo que puse en el título. Quiero ver mi página web desde mi computadora, pero Jquery no carga. Intenté desde otra computadora en mi casa y tampoco. Les hice probar a varios amigos y a todos les funciona bien el sitio. La página está alojada en hostinger. El soporte de hostinger me dijo que a ellos les carga bien, sin errores en la consola, y hasta me mandaron foto demostrándolo.
[image: Errores que salen en la consola del navegador (Mozilla)]

Todos esos errores me salen en el navegador (Mozilla). Qué puede estar pasando ? La pag es befittnes.com

Answer (score 0):

Usa este codigo: Ponlo en el head

```html
<script src="https //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" </script>
```

Comment: Te sugiero leer [answer] ¿podrías explicar por favor como este código soluciona el problema?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias de antemano por responder. Intenté y no funciona, no hay caso. A otra gente le funciona bien pero a mi no.. :/

Comment: Ok lo vás a lograr